# Nested where clauses codeigniter mysql query

Tags: codeigniter

Is there any way to get nested where clauses? e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (colA = 'valueA' AND colB = 'valueB') OR (colA = 'valueC' AND colB = 'valueD')
```

I know I could just write this into a `query` function call e.g.:

```
$this->db->query("SELECT ...")
```

But I was wondering if there was a "proper" way to do it in codeigniter e.g.:

```
$this->db->where(array('colA'=>'valueA'), array('colB'=>valueB'))->or_where(array('colA'=>'valueC'), array('colB'=>'valueD'))
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**With codeigniter 3, now there is, see the update!** 
<strike>There's no `where()` method usage variant with arrays that would allow you to do that.</strike> In these situations i usually just build the part in one long string like this:

```
$this->db->where("
    (
    (colA = '".$this->db->escape($v0)."' and colB = '".$this->db->escape($v1)."') 
    or 
    (colA = '".$this->db->escape($v2)."' and colB = '".$this->db->escape($v3)."') 
    )
");
```

Escaping can be done with `escape`(does some autodetection) or `escape_str` or `escape_like_str` manually depending on what the parameter expected to be or what the predicate in use.

If i'm on a project that uses the [Datamapper library](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/), i prefer to use the `group_start()` and `group_end()` methods when building these kind of queries, they have a [lot of different flavor](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/get.html#Query.Grouping) of these.

### Update

Now with, Codeigniter 3 which [have grouping methods](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping) in the query builder, so you can do `->group_start()`s and `->group_end()`s.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that! :) That's a bit better than doing the `$this->db->query("...")` version. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try like

```
$this->db->where(condition1);
$this->db->or_where(condition2);
```